# What is the default world state in Witcher 3, regarding decisions from Witcher 2?

Tags: the-witcher-3

At the start of ***The Witcher 3 - The Wild Hunt*** you can either

- import a savegame (PC only)
- select the decisions you made in Witcher 2 (*Simulate Witcher 2 Decisions*)
- skip the whole import of decisions

If you chose to select the decisions (or import a savegame) there are 5 major decisions which will have some kind of impact on the game.

**Care: *The Witcher 2 - Assassin of Kings* Spoilers ahead**

These decisions depend on if you:

1. killed or spared Aryan LaValette
2. sided with Iorveth or Roche
3. saved Triss or saved Saskia/Anais
4. saved Sile de Tancarville or let her die
5. killed or spared Letho

If you chose **not** to import any of your decisions, what will be the (supposedly default/canon) world-state regarding these decisions?

Just to clarify things: I'm not asking about the actual impact of decisions, I just want to know, what the game assumes on default if you don't import any decisions.

Answer (score 8):

After researching on the web for a good hour I stumbled across some of the answers and I will collect them here:

1. Aryan LaVlette was killed
2. Sided with Roche at the end of chapter 1
3. unknown :/ this is the only point that I couldn't find
4. Sile de Tancarville is dead
5. Letho was killed

If I find the answer to 3 I will update this answer. This is completely based on a lot of forum posts and some people who played through the default world state.

Comment: Could you please add the sourced for the answer.

Comment: @raznagul I could list 20 sites if I need to add my sources, that's the problem

Comment: saving Triss can be assumed to be the default canon story rewrite seeing as how Triss is in Witcher 3